# Analysis of pre-post data when 2 treatments given serially to same subjects

Tags: regression, anova, repeated-measures, clinical-trials, crossover-study

I have following data from a cross-over trial where subjects were given 2 types of treatments separated by a washout period. For each treatment measurement was made in pre and post treatment period. I want to determine if one treatment produced a greater change than other while correcting for pre level and taking into account repeat subject participation. Sample data is as follows:

```
id  tt  pre post change
1   1   5   9   4
2   1   6   8   2
3   1   2   7   5
1   2   4   6   2
2   2   5   8   3
3   2   6   9   3
```

How can I analyze this? I thought of following possibilities:

```
aov(change ~ tt * pre + Error(id), data=mydata)

aov(change ~ tt * pre + Error(id/(tt*pre)), data=mydata)

lm(change ~ tt * pre + id, data=mydata)

lmer(change ~ 1 + tt * pre + (1 | id), data=mydata)

lmer(change ~ 1 + tt * pre + (tt * pre | id), data=mydata)
```

Which of the above (or something else) is the correct approach?